# Вывод разных списков из базы данных

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, livedata

В репозитории переменной типа LiveData изначально присвоен запрос из БД (записи идут в алфавитном порядке). Как после запуска приложения и, например, нажатия на кнопку отсортировать список по другим параметрам и вывести на экран? Я пробовал переприсваивать переменной другой запрос, но ничего не менялось, также пробовал менять типы на MutableLiveData, но понял, что Dao не поддерживает MutableLiveData и если вызывать метод value у запроса из Dao с типом LiveData, то приложение не запустится. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант первый, и, на мой взгляд, правильный. Оторвать представление от модели. Подписчик получает данные и отдает их адаптеру RecyclerView. У этого же адаптера создаем параметры отображения, которые сортируют данные внутри адаптера как вам надо. При выборе пользователем другого вида сортировки меняются параметры адаптера, но не меняется подписчик и обсервбл.

Вариант второй, генерируем в рантайме запросы

```
 @Dao
 interface Dao {
     @RawQuery(observedEntities = MyEntry.class)
     LiveData<List<MyEntry>> getEntries(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
 }


LiveData<List<User>> liveUsers = rawDao.getUsers(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM MyEntry ORDER BY name DESC"));
```

Comment: Не меняется подписчик, имеется ввиду не переприсваивать переменной в репозитории другой запрос? Ведь тогда получается, что эта переменная будет ссылаться на другой объект LiveData

Comment: Не очень понял вопроса, но суть в том, что вы один раз получили от room объект LiveData, один раз подписались и если вдруг изменится фильтрация вам не нужно снова получать LiveData и/или подписываться на нее

Comment: вообще идея пересортировывать данные внутри адаптера - плохое решение, адаптер должен получать уже готовые данные в нужном порядке для отображения. Это скорее костыль

Comment: @pavloff Не могу согласиться с этим... Есть какие-то основания для такого утверждения? Генерация тучи LiveData кажется мне большим "преступлением", чем повышение расходов на сортировку. Если, конечно, речь не про миллионные списки, которые вы получаете с backpressure